# CNAME configuration for same domain

Tags: networking, dns, routing, cname

I am very new to the networking and server configuration so, I apologize if my question is very silly.

Basically, I have a site up and running and now I have decided to expand the site.

I have a domain named www.mydomain.example, now I want to create a similar page for different users. eg, user1.mydomain.example, user2.mydomain.example, user3.mydomain.example and so on.

The code is 80% similar for most of the users. So I was wondering if I can make the structure something like this:

[image: Stucture Illustration]

How should I configure the routing? Will the CNAME configuration outlined work? If not, what is the best way to establish such architecture?

If web server changes are required,  providing a simple example on how to get it going would be helpful.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about CNAME records, unless you are specifically pointing a service at a subdomain.

If you have your root domain `domain.example` and a `www` record only then you can concentrate on, say, using PHP and HTACCESS with a condition that if your subdomain matches whatever your structure then you can route this to your website script.

Sample DNS entries for fasthosts (note, this is a sample picture from the Internet (https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/euf/assets/KB_Images/UKDCP5/Domains/website-a-record.png)):

[image]

E.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?username=%1 [L]
```

Will redirect `kinnectus.domain.example` to `index.php?username=kinnectus` for further processing.

personally, I'd have some database driven mechanism to simplify things like if you have to migrate... individual HTMl files in different areas can be done, but it becomes a management nightmare...

Comment: I want to redirect a user to the subdirectory. user1 should redirect to src/user1/index.html. For such configuration, should I use the same mechanism? and where should I write this code to redirect the user?